# Suddenly I have USB 2/3 problems. Keyboard and mouse no longer function on blue 2/3 ports

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I have a roccat Kone+ mouse and a roccat ISKU | FX Multicolor gaming keyboard both of which have been fully supported in the past. Suddenly they no longer function. Right now, I'm using an old keyboard and mouse from my "parts closet". Suspect some kind of problematic update. Note that other devices work in these ports. Notably a Logitech Orbit camera. I've rebooted and reinstalled the roccat-tools package and so far have not discovered any solution. I've dumped the results of lsusb -v for 2 situations to file. One for when the keyboard is partially functioning on USB 1.0 ports and the other for the case when it doesn't work at all on USB 2/3 ports.

[Edit] By now, I know that it's strictly a USB issue and not a keyboard or mouse issue. If I reboot the machine, it takes some time after the login screen shows up for the keyboard to work, when it does. I'm now testing with a standard keyboard and mouse. I've tried downloading new USB Ids, but IDK if that even matters. It seems to me that it may be related to [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/807291).

[Plugged into USB 2.0](http://pastebin.com/v9jcdUR8)

[Plugged into USB 3.0](http://pastebin.com/T60ZMxQn)

Comment: There is no 3000 character limit. And you may upload long snippets to e.g. https://pastebin.com and share the link here.

Comment: You can upload images to https://imgur.com and share the link here. Please do not make screenshots of plain text though, upload them as text instead.

Comment: I've never seen a computer have USB 3 and USB 1.0. In fact, I've never seen a computer with USB 1.0, only USB 1.1. Also, USB 3 is blue, not USB 2.0. I suspect there's something wrong with your USB 3 driver.

Comment: Agreed. Apologies if I'm inexact.  My expertise isn't with hardware.

Answer (score 0):

In one sentence you say the keyboard "no longer functions", in another you say it's "partially functioning". Please clarify this.
Also please grab the manual of your board and plug the devices into USB2.0 connectors. USB3.0 is proven to sometimes make problems even under Windows.

Comment: Please write your query for more information in a comment.

Comment: Can't comment to otherones posts because I'm lacking 4 reputation points.

Comment: It varies and it doesn't seem consistent.  I know that I can plug into USB 1 ports and I will be able to get the keys to work but none of the other functions of the keyboard.  I have to shuffle the plugs around though before I can get this and as yet I've not been able to discern a clear pattern. That's USB 1. USB 3 usually doesn't work at all but sometimes I get lights on the keyboard. Sometimes the mouse will work but keys on keyboard never do.  Again, some shuffling is required to get the different behaviors.